# Sanctum unauthenticated response when Bearer token is set

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sanctum

When I try to enter an end-point, the Sanctum middleware throws an "Unauthenticated"(401) response. Whenever a user logs in, I encrypt the token and attach it as a cookie to the client side; after that, the user hits another end-point (/identify) where custom middleware decrypts the cookie and sets headers as a plain token. Tried to remove sanctum middleware from the end-point, and I was able to receive data from the controller, but when the auth:sanctum is there, I can't enter the route.

**LoginService**

```
public function login(object $request)
{
    // Get user
    $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();

    // create token
    $token = $user->createToken('Basic web token')->plainTextToken;

    // encrypt token
    $encryptedToken = Crypt::encryptString($token);

    // create cookie
    $cookie = Cookie::make('token', $encryptedToken, 60, null, null, false, true);

    return $this->successfullRequest([
        'token' => $encryptedToken,
        'user' => User::with(['profile', 'roles', 'permissions'])->find($user->id)
    ], 'User successfully logged in', 200)->withCookie($cookie);
}
```

**DecryptSanctumTokenMiddleware**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    // get encrypted cookie
    $encryptedToken = $request->cookie('token');

    // cookie is not attached
    if (!$encryptedToken) {
        return $this->failedRequest('', 'Unauthenticated', 401);
    }

    // decrypt cookie
    $decryptedToken = Crypt::decryptString($encryptedToken);

    // set headers
    $request->headers->set("Authorization", "Bearer $decryptedToken");

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Route endpoint**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/auth', 'middleware' => ['decryptCookie', 'auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::post('identify', [AuthController::class, 'identify']);
});
```

I've tried to dd() headers in the controller when auth:sanctum was removed from the route and could see the Authorization: Bearer token. I'm testing via postman; cookies are attached.

Answer (score 1):

Bearer token not work in new laravel so you can pass token as x-access-token and middleware convert into bearer token

First Create Middleware ParseTokenFromUrl

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ParseTokenFromUrl
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('accept','application/json');
        if ($request->header('x-access-token') && !$request->header('Authorization')){
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->header('x-access-token'));
            $request->headers->remove('x-access-token');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And call this middleware to middlewareGroups and middlewarePriority in Kernel.php

[image]

[image]

Comment: 'Bearer token not work in new laravel' What do you mean that Bearer tokens do not work in new laravel?

Comment: Bearer tokens are still used in latest 10.x Sanctum: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens

Comment: I'm pretty sure that my solution should work, because it works in client-side. However, it doesn't work via postman. I can log in and receive the token, but when trying to hit /identify endpoint, I receive unauthorized. Cookie is attached to postman as I see. Tried to clear cache&cookies from postman